# apply a function for every row of a matrix

Tags: r

I want to calculate a rate, which expresses the number of negative values out of all values, and I want to apply that in every row of a given matrix.

```
    func1<-function(N){
 alpha1 = 8.439e-02
 beta1 = 8.352e-01
 mu = 7.483e-03 
 omega = 1.343e-04
 X_0 = -3.092031e-02
 sigma_0 = 0.03573968
 eps = rt (N,7.433e+00)
 # loops
 Xn= numeric (N)
 sigma= numeric (N)
 sigma[1] = sigma_0
 Xn[1] = X_0
 for (t in 2:N){
 sigma[t] = sqrt (omega + alpha1 * (Xn[t-1])^2 + beta1* (sigma[t-1])^2)
 Xn[t] = sigma[t] * eps[t]
 }
 A = mu + Xn
 return(A)
 }
 M<-replicate(1000,func1(420))
 M2<-t(M)

    func<-function(x){
     count<-as.numeric()
     count[1]=0
  for(i in 1:420){
    if(x[i]<0){
      count[i+1]=count[i]+1
    }
    else{count[i+1]=count[i]
    }
  }
  return(count)

x<-as.vector(x)
 count<-func(x)
  finalcount<-count[421]
  rate<-finalcount/420
}
apply(M2,1,func)
```

M2 is the matrix I would like to use, and X expresses the row substitute into the function

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do. You have a return statement, and then some more code in the function. Also, in the last line, what is `M`?

Comment: If you want the proportion of negative values in a matrix, you can do something like this: `m <- matrix(-9:10, nrow = 5); sum(m < 0) / length(m);`

Comment: M is the matrix, and I need to get the rate for every row of M.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your matrix and expected output? The above code can't be run.

Comment: If your matrix is something like this: `m <- matrix(-9:10, nrow = 5)`, you can get the proportion of negative values per row by doing `apply(m, 1, function(x) sum(x < 0)  / length(x))`. Is that what you want?

Comment: I think sum(x<0) are adding up all negative values, but I just want to count the negative numbers, like there are 3 negative number in a list of 10 numbers, then the rate will be 3 out of 10.

Comment: `sum(x < 0)` will count the number negative numbers in `x`. Did you try and see what it actually is doing?

Comment: Yes, I have tried, and I got it. Thx a lot

Comment: I posted an answer below with an even more efficient way than `apply`. Take a look.

Comment: By the way, can you please tell me why my code cannot apply on each row of the matrix? I have tried for a specific row, which could get a rate.

Comment: Your function is saving up cumulative occurrences of negative numbers. You don't need count as a vector of values in that function. Try modifying that function to: `func<-function(x){
    count <- 0
    for(i in 1:length(x){
        if(x[i]<0){
            count <- count + 1
        }
    }
    return(count / length(x))}`

Comment: Thank you. And if I want to add up all negative values, and apply on every row of the matrix. what shouid I do?

Comment: `sum(x[x < 0])`. You will see, x < 0 just gives a logical vector of which values are less than zero or not. Indexing `x` with that vector gives you the actual values that are less than zero.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is on way to do it:

Let us say you create a matrix as follows:

```
m <- matrix(-9:10, nrow = 5)
m

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   -9   -4    1    6
[2,]   -8   -3    2    7
[3,]   -7   -2    3    8
[4,]   -6   -1    4    9
[5,]   -5    0    5   10
```

There are two negative numbers per row except the last one.

Proportion of negative numbers per row can be computed as follows:

```
rowMeans(m < 0)
[1] 0.50 0.50 0.50 0.50 0.25
```

You can use `apply` if you like as follows, but that loops through each row:

```
apply(m, 1, function(x) sum(x < 0)  / length(x))
[1] 0.50 0.50 0.50 0.50 0.25
```